# Where did the Haganai and Oreimo cameo appear?

Tags: oreimo, boku-wa-tomodachi-ga-sukunai

It's been a while seen I last watched [haganai](/questions/tagged/haganai) and [oreimo](/questions/tagged/oreimo), and I remember there was a cameo role in a certain episode. Problem is, I don't even remember in which of the two anime and season it happened, just that there was a cameo of the main group of characters.

Can someone point out to me where it appeared and what happened in the cameo? Also, was it reciprocated by the other anime in the pair?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Boku wa Tomodachi ga Sukunai Season 1 episode 11 around 04.31

[image]

[Wikia also mention this cameo](http://haganai.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_11#Trivia)

Comment: Aah, so it was the OreImo cast in Haganai. Thanks :)